# Signature of C++ copy constructor for struct with an enum

Tags: c++, enums, struct, copy-constructor

Is there a reason why the implicit copy constructor for a struct containing an enum would *not* use the `const` version - or why there is no copy-constructor at all? I would expect an implicit copy-constructor being created, i.e.:

```
X(const X& x)
```

I know there are rules for when this might happen, for instance if a member variable does not have a copy constructor, or a non-const copy constructor. I guess my question is how this relates to enums - and if it is this rule that applies?

Adding my own copy constructor seems to work.

Example - what, if any, copy-constructors are created implicitly:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int myInt;
  double myDouble; 
  MyEnum myEnum;
};
```

Comment: Since when does C++ synthesise copy constructors when it can’t? If one of the members cannot be copied then there is simply no automatic copy constructor generated, end of story.

Comment: If it's implicit can you explain how you know the copy constructor has this signature? Does `int main() { const X x1; X x2(x1); }` not work?

Comment: Please give a specific example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Edited the question a bit. To answer your questions: (1) I don't know if there's a copy-constructor at all.
  The struct contains only doubles, ints and the enum. I would have thought a const copy-constructor to be implicitly created then?

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example that demonstrates your problem, as described at http://sscce.org.

Comment: What behaviour are you observing that leads you to believe that a copy constructor is not being generated, or that a non-const copy constructor is being generated?

Comment: Trying to use the struct with standard containers does not work. Adding my own const copy-constructor to the struct fixes the problem.

Comment: @Magnus we will never figure out the problem by guessing at it. Please post a complete example, that includes the definition of MyEnum, the definition of MyStruct, and the way you are trying to use MyStruct in a standard container, that we can try to compile ourselves and see the errors for ourselves. Then we can tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess about enums is wrong; the problem is somewhere else. The following code compiles with no problem if no copy constructor is explicitly defined, and fails to compile if there is a copy constructor taking a non-const reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

enum MyEnum {
  e0, e1, e2
};

struct MyStruct {
  int myInt;
  double myDouble; 
  MyEnum myEnum;
  // MyStruct(MyStruct& ){} // uncomment to make compilation fail
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyStruct& s) {
  out<<"{"<<s.myInt<<","<<s.myDouble<<","<<s.myEnum<<"}";
  return out;
}

int main() {
  MyStruct s = {42, 3.1415926, e0};
  MyStruct s1 = s;
  std::vector<MyStruct> v(10, s1);
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<MyStruct>(std::cout,"\n"));
  return 0;
}
```

As others pointed out in comments, a realistic example demonstrating the error is required to understand what's the real problem.

Comment: You are right. The problem is elsewhere in the code. My problem is that I don't have access to all of it. The funny(?) thing is that when I implement my own copy-constructor and call `push_back`, it never returns. I guess memory and/or thread problems somewhere. If I haven't messed up the constructor of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit out of my expertise.

When you try to construct an `X` from a non-const lvalue instance of `X`, the signature `X(X& )` would be a closer match, and be chosen.

Comment: But only if both forms are declared which can only happen if they are both user-declared.